# How to create multiple sequence numbers when using a transaction with Redis ServiceStack

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

I'm trying to insert multiple new entities into Redis using C# ServiceStack. The problem I am having is generating the sequence numbers.

From what I've read you cannot make other requests whilst queueing the transaction commands to garauntee an atomic action.

This would then mean having to iterate over my entities collection to first generate the sequence numbers and then iterating again to queue the transaction commands and execute?

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

```
IRedisClientsManager RedisManager;

RedisManager.ExecTrans(x =>
{
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        x.QueueCommand(c =>
        {
            //entity.Id = generate sequence number
            c.Store(entity);
        });
    }
    x.Commit();
});
```

Comment: What happens if you do not set Id manually, will redis set it up automatically?

Comment: I need the object being updated with Id at that point. Otherwise it would require another round trip to update the Id afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pre-fetch a batch of sequence ids then assign them to your models. You can also use `StoreAll()` which takes advantage of Redis's batch [MSET](http://redis.io/commands/mset) operation so all models get executed/stored in the same operation.

Given this, I would re-write the above with something like:

```
RedisManager.ExecAs<TEntity>(r => {
   var maxSeqId = r.GetNextSequence(entities.Count);
   var newId = maxSeqId - entities.Count;
   entities.ForEach(x => x.Id = newId++);
   r.StoreAll(entities);
});
```